# Silverstripe - set a default value for Varchar populated via DropdownField

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm having trouble setting a default database value for my Size field, which is populated by a Silverstripe `DropdownField()` from an array of values.

```
class PartnerLogo extends DataObject {

  ...

  private static $db = array(
    "Size" => "Varchar(255)"
  );

  private static $defaults = array(
    "Size" => "sm"
  );

  public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = new FieldList(new TabSet("Root"));

    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", 
      new DropdownField("Size[]", "Size", 
        array( 
          "xs" => "Extra Small", 
          "sm" => "Small", 
          "md" => "Medium", 
          "lg"=> "Large" 
        ), 
        "sm"
      )
    );

    return $fields;

  }

  ...

}
```

In the CMS, if I create a new record and click Save, the `Size` field is empty. Is it possible to give `Size` a default value string?

I'm using Silverstripe 3.5. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Note adding the square brackets after `Size` in `DropdownField()` appears to be the only way to get the default value parameter (or `setValue()`) to work. This makes the dropdown show "Small" when the record is first created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to use the `populateDefaults()` function instead of the `$defaults` array in this instance. It also meant I could remove the square brackets and final parameter from the `DropdownField` function (see my comment on the question):

```
class PartnerLogo extends DataObject {

  ...

  private static $db = array(
    "Size" => "Varchar(255)"
  );

  public function populateDefaults() {
    $this->Size = "sm";
    parent::populateDefaults();
  }

  public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = new FieldList(new TabSet("Root"));

    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", 
      new DropdownField("Size", "Size", 
        array( 
          "xs" => "Extra Small", 
          "sm" => "Small", 
          "md" => "Medium", 
          "lg"=> "Large" 
        )
       )
    );

    return $fields;

  }

  ...

}
```

It's possible that the documentation is incorrect, or should at least make a note that you can't set the default value of a `Varchar` to a string like you can for the `Enum` in the example (under "Default Values"): https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/data_types_and_casting/

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem. Try setting the default value on the dropdown field by replacing your `getCMSFields` function with the code below.

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = new FieldList(new TabSet("Root"));

    $fields->addFieldToTab(
        "Root.Main",
        DropdownField::create("Size", "Size")
            ->setSource(
                array(
                "xs" => "Extra Small",
                "sm" => "Small",
                "md" => "Medium",
                "lg" => "Large",
                )
            )->setValue("sm") //set the default value to small
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, I just tried it again to confirm. If I put square brackets (`[]`) after `Size`, it makes "sm" the default value in the dropdown (not sure why that works) but the value in the database is still blank until I change the dropdown selection and save. `populateDefaults()` appears to be the way to go. I'll accept my answer after two days.